# HTML Redirect To Root

Tags: php, html, asp.net, redirect

I understand how to get a page to redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=http://example.com/" />
```

I need a 10-20 second delay (shown above) to let my visitors see that their data was successfully collected.

We have the following sites:

- local PC: `http://localhost`
- employee TEST: `http://dev.example.com`
- customer BETA: `http://beta.example.com`
- LIVE: `http://www.example.com`

Obviously, I do not want to change the code on my PC after it is working so that it works in the employee test environment, our change it again when it goes out to beta, or yet again before it goes LIVE.

The redirect, like the one above, would be used after someone submits a form on our website.

### How would I create a redirect that knows its location?

My current task is to find out how to do this in PHP, so I might be able to write the tag before the page is served.

But, I also develop pages in ASP.NET for other customers, so I would like to see ways to do this that can be handled in Windows as well.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` has the current hostname. You could also just make the refresh relative: `...url=/"...`. `/` means the root of the host.

Comment: Question was unclear: Added the fact that I need a 10-20 second delay before the redirect.

Comment: so echo `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in the meta refresh instead of just hard coding the host. Or like I said, just make url= `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your redirect tag to point to the url `/` which will always be the root path of the domain you're on.

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; url=/" />`

Comment: If that works, it is exactly what I'm looking for! That same code will work in PHP or ASP.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header('location: /'); //or header('location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}
```

With jQuery setTimeout function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/'; }, 10000);  //10.000 milliseconds delay
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php) you can learn more about the PHP SERVER super global and follow this link to the PHP [header()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.header.php) function.

### Using ajax to send requests to the server

If you use jQuery, you should probably think about this solution: Request the PHP file via ajax and do your database update or some serverside stuff. If it was successful, display a message and redirect after some time.

Example:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    var inputs = $(this).serialize(); //safe the submitted data
    $.post('path_to_file.php', inputs, function(data) {  //returned a json array
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);  //decode the json data
        if('errors' in data) {  //were there any errors?
            $.each(data['errors'], function() {
                $('#error-box').append(this); //show the error message
            });
        } else {  //if no errors
            $('#succes-box').html('Update was successful.');
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '/'; }, 10000); //Redirect after 10s
        }
    });
});
```

**path_to_file.php**

```
<?php
//Do something with post data.....
$response = array();
if(!$query) {
    $response['errors'][] = 'There was an error querying the database.';  //error example
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need that 10-20 second delay to let my visitors see that their data was collected. Your version zips them straight there. Let me add that to my question.

Comment: You can do that using javascript, added it to the answer.

Comment: @jp2code, If we're talking about redirecting after a post which updates the database, you need to do it instantly. Save a message in the session or something and display it on the next page, But if you don't redirect instantly, you'll start getting double submissions.

Comment: Or you post it via ajax and then if it was successful, show a message and redirect after some time